# Serializing a form in jQuery doesn't include text box values in it

Tags: jquery, html, serialization

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(":submit").click(function () {
                var rec = $("*").serialize();
                var r = JSON.stringify(rec);
                alert(r);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" id="f">FORM<br /><br />
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" /><br /><br />
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" value="a"/><br /><br />
    Gender :
    <input type="radio" id="r1" /> <label for="r1">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="r2" /> <label for="r2">Female</label><br /><br />
    Favourite Ride :
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1"/> <label for="c1">AUDI Q3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2"/> <label for="c2">Jaguar XJ L</label><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="b1" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

It is serializing the mode of radio and checkboxes but it left the textbox values. The value of r is the value of of radio button and checkbox, but I need textbox value also. Can anyone direct me correctly?

Comment: `$("*").serialize();` seems to be a bad idea but you forgot `name` attribute in the text boxes.

Comment: Btw, feel free to use the "correct" submit-event syntax: `$("form").submit(function (evt) { ... })`

Comment: But how can i get the serialized array to my grid,as it is showing the values as "name":"fname","value":"peter" like this.i need it as json data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialize the input text boxes they need a `name=` value too.

To allow for keyboard submissions, and as`OzrenTkalcecKrznaric` mentioned, you should connect to the form's `submit` event and not `click` on the buttons:

e.g.

```
$('form#f').submit(function(e){
     var rec = $(this).serialize();
     var r = JSON.stringify(rec);
     alert(r);
});
```

That also means that `this` is the form so you can focus `serialize` on just its elements.

Comment: But how can i get the serialized array to my grid,as it is showing the values as "name":"fname","value":"peter" like this.i need it as json data .

Comment: Simply don't call stringify! Raw JSON data in this context is just the in-memory object with properties.